# How can i set route for action with string parameter for username and password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have action in controller with this code:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "members")]  
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult login(string uname,string pass)
    {

        MembersSrv mm = new MembersSrv();
         if (mm.validateUsers(uname,pass)==true)
        {
            mm.CreateCookie(uname, pass);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
         }
        else
             return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```

how can i get this url?

> ```
> http://localhost:5555/Members/Login
> ```

is this route true?

```
      routes.MapRoute(
               "Login", // Route name
               "Members/{action}/{Uname}", // URL with parameters
               new { action = "Login", Uname =" " } // Parameter defaults
               );
```

Comment: why do you need to set it like that ? Does the default routing not working when accessing that url ? what is your controller name ? The code shows it is an HTTPPOST action. Why you need to access that in URL ?

Comment: i want to access members login page by this:
http://localhost:54465/Members/Login
but i can't , and dont know what i do :/

Comment: That method is HTTPPOST. Dont you have a GET Action for that ?

Comment: to show the login page ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `GET` action for that

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
  return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles = "members")]  
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult login(string uname,string pass) 
{
  //your code handle login when form posted
}
```

This can be accessed like

```
http://yourdomainname/members/login
```

Assuming `login` action belongs to `membersController`.

When user posts the form, your `HttpPost` action method will handle that.

You may not need those routes you defined. you will be fine with the default routes you have.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: i cant access this url, may be my codes are incorrect, I don't know:(

Comment: do you have a sample solution i can look at ?

Answer (score 0):

The route of Members Area is :

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
     {
         context.MapRoute(
             "Members_default",
             "Members/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             new { action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
     }
```

can I change it to:

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Members_default",
            "Members/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```